# Can I write an RSpec test that expects a method to be called with an Object as an argument, and that Object to have a particular property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test out that a method gets called with a custom Ruby object as an argument, and that that object has the correct attribute.

This is working right now:

`expect(MyClass).to receive(:a_method).with(instance_of(SomeObject))`

but I can't find anything about how to test the internals of SomeObject

I want something like:

`expect(MyClass).to receive(:a_method).with(instance_of(SomeObject)).with_attribute(:name => "Bob")`

but this throws a NoMethodError

Comment: it should not matter how SomeObject is defined, since you're testing that the method is getting called. In theory, there should be a spec for `:a_method` in `MyClass` specs that exercises what you're trying to solve here

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you mean that I shouldn't test the inner workings of `SomeObject` when testing `:a_method`? In my particular circumstance, `MyClass::some_other_method` gets called with different parameters. `:some_method` always ends up getting called with SomeObject as an argument when I test :some_other_method, but depending on those parameters `:some_other_method` gets called with, the attributes in SomeObject change.

Comment: yeah, `SomeObject` inner stuff is not relevant here, but, I think it's right to expect an instance of that class.

Comment: gotcha thanks. I think there might be a better way about it. :)

Answer (score -1):

from rspec 3.1, you could use [have-attributes-matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/have-attributes-matcher) to do that.

```rb
expect(object).to receive(:foo)
.with(have_attributes(first_name: 'Hans', last_name: 'Dampf'))
```

There's case that this will be failed: when the argument objects are `Comparable` objects, in that case you could check the specific attribute `object_id` or using the `an_object_equal_to` matcher, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534773/rspec-how-to-expect-a-method-be-called-with-a-comparable-object-instance-exactly/69534796#69534796).