# RSpec: How to compare have_received arguments by object identity?

Tags: ruby, rspec, object-identity

i used to using `expect(subject/double).to haved_received(:a_method).with(args).exactly(n).times` to test that a method be called with some specific arguments and be called exactly {n} times. But today it's broken with arguments are `Comparable` objects, take a look at the below code:

setup

```rb
class A; end

class B
 include Comparable
 attr_reader :val

 def initialize(val)
   @val = val
 end

 def <=>(other)
   self.val <=> other.val
 end
end

class S
 def call(x); end
end

s = S.new
allow(s).to receive(:call)
```

now the below test passed with normal object A

```rb
a1 = A.new
a2 = A.new

s.call(a1)
s.call(a2)

expect(s).to have_received(:call).with(a1).exactly(1).times
expect(s).to have_received(:call).with(a2).exactly(1).times
```

but it failed with `Comparable` object B

```rb
b1 = B.new(0)
b2 = B.new(0)

s.call(b1)
s.call(b2)

expect(s).to have_received(:call).with(b1).exactly(1).times
expect(s).to have_received(:call).with(b2).exactly(1).times
```

i debug and saw that the rspec matcher call the spaceship operator `<=>` to verify arguments, so it considers b1 and b2 are the same

```rb
Failure/Error: expect(s).to have_received(:call).with(b1).exactly(1).times
expected: 1 time with arguments:
received: 2 times with arguments:
```

What should i do to pass the test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `Comparable` implements [`==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Comparable.html#method-i-3D-3D), so your objects are treated as being equal in regards to `==`:

```
b1 = B.new(0)
b2 = B.new(0)

b1 == b2 #=> true
```

To set a constraint based on object identity, you can use the [`equal`](https://rspec.info/documentation/3.10/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers.html#equal-instance_method) matcher: (or its aliases `an_object_equal_to` / `equal_to`)

```
expect(s).to have_received(:call).with(an_object_equal_to(b1)).once
```

Under the hood, this matcher calls [`equal?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#equal-3F-method):

```
b1 = B.new(0)
b2 = B.new(0)

b1.equal?(b2) #=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution: using [the `have_attributes` matcher](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers:have_attributes) to check exactly `object_id` of the object argument

```rb
expect(s).to have_received(:call).with(have_attributes(object_id: b1.object_id))
.exactly(1).times

expect(s).to have_received(:call).with(have_attributes(object_id: b2.object_id))
.exactly(1).times
```